# How to efficiently index and query JSON field data in SOLR?

Tags: postgresql, search, indexing, solr

What is the best way to index data from Postgres that contains a field with lengthly nested JSONB data.

**POSTGRES FIELD (json_db_field):**

```
{
  ...
  "field_name": "field_value",
  "columns": [
      {
          "nested_key": "nested_value_1",
          ...
      },
      {
          "nested_key": "nested_value_1",
          ...
      },
    ],
    ...
}
```

As of right now I am indexing the field like so:

```
<field name="json_db_field" type="my_text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" default="{}"/>

<fieldType name="my_text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I can query this field by including it in the query field:

```
 qf=json_db_field
```

This is quite slow to query, therefore I think its best to change this setup as in the future this could cause problems.

1. Should I flatten the JSON field out first in Postgres to a new table with columns for each object item?
2. Is there a way to index this field in SOLR that I can efficiently query?

Answer (score 1):

There are different way to bring JSON data into Solr, although -in my opinion- Solr can be filled more ideally with XML (using DIH) than JSON content.

But if you store JSON, you shoulnd't store this as simple text filed.
Btw: posting your `my_text_general` field definition would be helpful.

> Should I flatten the JSON field out first in Postgres to a new table with columns for each object item?

I would'n do that. migrating an object oriented structure in an flat structure will work, but mostly you will find different problems on that way.

> Is there a way to index this field in SOLR that I can efficiently query?

There are different ways and also different Questions how to indiex JSON an Solr, including a part of the JSON structure, by using something near to "nested documents".

Take a look at this:

[indexing-nested-documents-in-solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983061/indexing-nested-documents-in-solr)

[Nested Child Documents](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments)

//Update
Looking at your field definition, I would not use that much filters. But this depends on your needs. Mostly you like to search one exactly term, like `columns`. Probably you dont like to find also `column`. For that you should only use minimal filters, like `lowerCase` and something like `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory`

Take a llok at this to see, what is possible: [Solr Analyzers, Tokenizers, and Token Filters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)

Comment: I have updated the post to include the field definition.